# Android - access native functions in a pre-compiled library

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, static-libraries

I'd like to use the native OpenCV function [`getThreshVal_Otsu_8u`](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/thresh.cpp#L603-662) in my Android application.  I've noticed that the external OpenCV Java wrapper functions call functions defined as `native`, but which don't have the same names as the actual native functions.  For example:

Java function:

```
double threshold(Mat src, Mat dst, double thresh, double maxval, int type)
```

Java "native" function:

```
private static native double threshold_0(long src_nativeObj, long dst_nativeObj, double thresh, double maxval, int type)
```

C++ function:

```
double cv::threshold( InputArray _src, OutputArray _dst, double thresh, double maxval, int type )
```

How can I make a similar `native` Java function to call into `getThreshVal_Otsu_8u`?  Is there some way to avoid rebuilding the OpenCV libraries and just "tunnel" into the existing `.lib` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is not already the case, you first need to set up your Android project in order to use the Java Native Interface ([this link might help](https://coderwall.com/p/nakhrq?i=1&p=1&q=&t%5B%5D=%21%21mine&t%5B%5D=%21%21bookmarks)).

Once it is set up, the principle is quite easy:

- You need to create a Java native prototype in your Java code (e.g. `public native void yourFunction();`)
- The corresponding function must be defined in your C/C++ file (e.g. `JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_your_package_JavaClassName_yourFunction(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj);`)
- You should be able to include the OpenCV library in your C/C++ code (e.g. `#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>`)

The method you want to use (i.e. `getThreshVal_0tsu_8u`) takes a `Mat&` as a parameter and returns a double, which means you will need to adapt your jni code correspondingly.

Comment: Thanks, looks good.  So I won't have to recompile the libraries after all?

Comment: You will need to import the OpenCV library in your workspace and link it to your project, but you won't have to compile it indeed. There are sample codes about this in the OpenCV documentation!